# Draft is empty when composing in TypeApp Mail (fromaly Type Mail and Blue Mail)

Tags: android, email

When I open a draft email with the android app "type mail" all previous contents gets deleted and I start with an empty body.
The body gets deleted immediately when I open the email, even if I exit the composing without saving any changes.
How can I resume editing my draft emails with their actual contents?

As I noticed since version 1.8.1.4 or earlier only the attachments get still deleted. So it seems like there was some improvement in the meantime.

Comment: Meanwhile I also found this interesting post [Why I Stopped Using Blue Mail (Type Mail)](http://www.sklar.com/2014/10/14/blue-mail/)

Comment: I realized K-9 Mail is a good and open source alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I got the anser from the Type developers:

> Type your response ABOVE THIS LINE to reply Frank Breitling Subject:
>   Reporting a bug/issue FEB 08, 2016  |  02:44PM UTC TypeApp Team
>   replied:
>
> Hi Frank,
>
> Thanks for sharing this!
>
> We are aware of this issue and is in our list of bugs to be fixed. If
>   we will need more info, we might contact you with some additional
>   questions.
>
> Thanks for your patience.
>
> In regards to the creating a draft in TypeApp and then opening on PC,
>   could you please let us know which PC / WebMail client you user (The
>   full name, please).
>
> Please let us know if you have any additional questions or feedback,
>   and we will gladly help! Cheers, Type Team
>
> ---
>
> FEB 07, 2016  |  07:43PM UTC Original message Frank wrote:
>
> Dear Type Team,
>
> It happens when I edit drafts with the app that have been created from
>   a PC. And it happens on all my accounts.
>
> I also noticed that when I edit drafts with a PC that have been
>   created with the app the attachments remain but the text disappears.
>
> Cheers
>
> Frank